# is x-frowarded for included in the request

Tags: httprequest

I have come to know that x forwarded for gives the ip address o the client who actually sent the request(getremoteaddress() returns the ip address of the machine that sent the reques to the server which can be a proxy).
 Anyway my question is where is the x forwarded for included in the request. How to extract the client address from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading the fine Wikipedia article first:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

The method for extracting the information from the headers will depend on your platform (which you haven't provided in your question).

Please be aware that `X-Forwarded-For` headers can be spoofed, and that the machine sending the request may simply pretend to be a proxy and put a fake IP address into the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

You should only trust `X-Forwarded-For` headers from your own proxies, not remote ones.